# Can I send performSegueWithIdentifier: to anything other than self?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a category on `UIViewController` that deals with errors coming from my networking layer. If I get an authentication error in response to a network call, I want to perform an unwind segue which takes me back to my `LoginViewController`.

However, I don't want to have to add the appropriate unwind segue to **every single** view controller in my Storyboard. Can I simply declare the unwind segue in the `UITabBarController` that is at the "top" of my view controller navigation, and then say

`[self.tabBarController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UnwindToLoginSegueIdentifier" sender:self]`

... from inside my `UIViewController`+`ErrorHandling` category?

Comment: I can't find anything about the validity of sending `performSegueWithIdentifier:` to anything other than self in the docs and when I try it, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS—but I'm not sure if that's me doing something else stupid.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. The unwind segue has to come from the controller you're unwinding from, and all segues need to be connected from a particular instance in the storyboard. The login view controller really should be one that's presented modally, not be one of the tabs, since you only need it briefly, then it should go away. If you set up your app that way, you can present and dismiss it from any controller (present it without animation from the controller in the first tab, if that's what you want the user to see when the app launches). You'll still have to have code in every controller to do that, unless you make a common base controller with that functionality that all the other controllers inherit from.

Comment: Well, I've fixed the (tangentially related) problem that was causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS and it's now working. Can you provide a reference to some documentation?

Comment: @RobertAtkins, what's working, and what documentation are you talking about? Actually when I think about it, I'm not sure what an unwind means when you have it in a tab bar controller. Normally, an unwind undoes a series of pushes and/or presentations, but the tabs in a tab bar controller don't have that kind of relationship to the tab bar controller. From which controller do you have the segue called "UnwindToLoginSegueIdentifier" setup in the storyboard?

Comment: Calling [self.tabBarController performSegue...] correctly triggers the unwind segue, from an arbitrary VC nested inside a navigation controller which is one of the roots of the tab bar controller. The unwind segue, declared on the tab bar controller, unwinds to the login controller, which (modally) pushed the tab bar controller in the first place. I'm looking for documentation that says you can or you can't send `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, or something that supports your statement "The unwind segue has to come from the controller you're unwinding from", because that's not what I observe.

Comment: Ok, you're setup is not what I thought you had. You are in fact calling it on the controller its connected from by calling the performSegue on self.tabBarController. So what you're observing is consistent with what I said. The fact that you can call it from any controller is because you can reference the controller the segue is attached to (the tab bar controller) from any controller. You don't need to call it literally on "self", just on the controller the segue emanates from.